# Does wsimport tool from JAX-WS allows to create RESTful class clients?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsimport

Im using wsimport but I cant find why or how to create classes for RESTful web services/ports defined in WSDL.

Does wsimport tool from JAX-WS allows to create RESTful class clients?

Answer (score 0):

No wsimport is only used for JAX-WS not JAX-RS. It reads WSDL file rather than WADL.

Comment: then why in wsdl its possible to describe RESTful web services?

Comment: wsimport will generate SOAP based stubs, not REST style.

Comment: is there possibility to generate class(stub) clients for REST webservices defined in WSDL?
Similar to wsimport.